# NextJS13, why I get 'Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]).'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm freaking out about this error and don't understand how to fix it. Here is my code :

```
'use client'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import AnimatedDiv from '../../../(shop)/(components)/animatedDiv'
import ProfileSection from './profileSection'
import AccountSection from './accountSection'
import SubscriptionSection from './subscriptionSection'

const SettingsPageOrchestrator = () => {
  const [renderedSection, setRenderedSection] = useState('Profile')

  return (
    <div >
      <div >
        <button          
          onClick={() => setRenderedSection('Profile')}
        >
          Profile
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => setRenderedSection('Account')}
        >
          Account
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => setRenderedSection('Subscription')}
        >
          Subscription and billing
        </button>
      </div>
      <InnerSection section={renderedSection} />
    </div>
  )
}

const InnerSection = ({ section }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {section === 'Profile' && (
        <AnimatedDiv>
          <ProfileSection />
        </AnimatedDiv>
      )}
      {section === 'Account' && (
        <AnimatedDiv>
          <AccountSection />
        </AnimatedDiv>
      )}
      {section === 'Subscription' && (
        <AnimatedDiv>
          <SubscriptionSection />
        </AnimatedDiv>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default SettingsPageOrchestrator
```

This is the component where I get the error :

```
import React from 'react'
import ProfileContent from './profileContent'
import ProfileSkeletron from './profileSkeletron'
import { SETTINGS_PROFILE_USER } from '../../../../apiUtils/costants'

import { getAuthenticatedServerSide } from '../../../../apiUtils/utils'
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth'
import { authOptions } from '../../../../pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]'

const ProfileSection = async () => {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions)
  const data = await getAuthenticatedServerSide(
    session?.user?.access_token,
    SETTINGS_PROFILE_USER
  )

  return (
    <div>
      <ProfileContent data={data} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default ProfileSection
```

I didn't understand why I get this error 'Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.'

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: Your component is `async` which means it returns a promise - just as the error is telling you. You can probably move `getServerSession` and `getAuthenticatedServerSide` outside of the component in its own `async` function, and then just remove `async` from the component.

Comment: You cannot call a server component (which uses `await` directly in render fn) from a client component - https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/fundamentals

Comment: how can I fetch the data if i remove await ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React is complaining about this:

```
const ProfileSection = async () => {
-------------------------^
```

> Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise])

Your component is `async` which means it's returning a promise but React can't work with that.

Probably the easiest solution (for now) would be to move the async function inside a `useEffect`, and then set local state with the data it returns. You can then use that state in your component.

In the long term you may want to think about at what point you want that data available, or if it's going to be available to more than one component. At which point you may need to reach for global state solution ([of which there are many](https://blog.openreplay.com/top-6-react-state-management-libraries-for-2022/)), or perhaps [a custom hook](https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks#custom-hooks-sharing-logic-between-components) to contain that stateful logic for reuse.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function ProfileSection() {

  const [ data, setData ] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      const session = await getServerSession(authOptions)
      const data = await getAuthenticatedServerSide(
        session?.user?.access_token,
        SETTINGS_PROFILE_USER
      );
      setData(data);
    }
    getData();
  }, []);

  if (!data) return <div>No profile</div>;

  return (
    <div>
      <ProfileContent data={data} />
    </div>
  );

}

export default ProfileSection
```

Comment: For completeness this is not entirely true; you can call await directly in Server Components (which are declared as async) which perhaps he saw somewhere in NextJS 13 Beta docs, but since he's calling the component from a client component (`'use client'`) it wouldn't work